# Laravel problema de agrupaciones a nivel de query (con subconsultas)

Tags: laravel, querybuilder

estoy con un problema que me está llevando bastante tiempo, se trata de agrupaciones en las querys con subconsultas. Hice una pregunta parecida hoy pero como la estoy intentando enfocar de diferente forma creo que es mejor crear otra pues es otro enfoque.

Tenemos

```
+-----------------+-------+-+------------+
|name             |level  | | victorias  |
+-----------------+-------+-+------------+
|ernesto          |100|     |   10       |
|ernesto          |100|     |   100      |
|javier           |100|     |   100      |
|javier           |100|     |   100      |
|ernesto          |120|     |   12       |
|javier           |120|     |   120      |
|enrique          |120|     |   12       | 
|enrique          |110|     |   11       |
|jose             |230|     |   230      |
|jose             |140|     |   140      |
|angel            |100|     |   10       |
|angel            |140|     |   140      |
|enrique          |100|     |   100      |
+-----------------+-------+-+------------+
```

Tengo un buscador donde puedo poner : **nombre, nivel o un chekbox **. El checkbox indica que traiga el nivel mas alto, si al buscar, el campo nombre esta vacio traigo todos los nombres pero de los nombres mas altos, si hay algo escrito pues igual mas un `where like`.

asi que la consulta es algo asi cuando el **checkbox** no esta marcado:

```
$collection = Model::where('name',like,'%$name%')->where('level',$level)->where('victorias',$victorias)->get();
```

Con esta query de arriba traeria lo que son las busquedas directas, no os preocupes de la clausula **where** para el nivel si viene vacio,  lo he peusto asi para simplificar (lo mismo con victoria).

Ahora el problema que tengo es que, si se pulsa el check (traer los pj con lvl mas altos con el **mismo nombre**) **me obliga la funcion de agregado** hacer un **un group by** por todos los campos que no no tengan la funcion de agregado y tengas en el select, sino te dara error. **¿Que pasa con esto?** pues que si yo quiero que las victorias este en segundo plano en todo esto **pero necesite mostrarlas como info adicional** me crea el problema de que no se *agrupen como a mi me interesa* .

Yo estoy intentando decirle a laravel (*y a mysql*): **Oye laravel, mira, traeme los personajes con mas level, agrupados obviamente por su level y nombre pero porfavor no me crees problemas con ese campo adicional que tengo que traery me estas obligando a meter en el group by sin querer hacerlo porque toda la demas info me es util**

Entonces recurro a **subconsultas**:

```
Model::where('name', 'like', $name)
    ->where('level', function($query) use ($name) {
        return $query->where("name", 'like', $name)->selectRaw('max(a.level) as level')->from('model as a');
    })
```

Pero no consigo dar con la tecla, el problema esta en que si pones todo en el **groupy by** para que deje de quejarse no obtengo nada util.. pues lo vuelve a agrupar y lo saca como estaba, mi idea con esa subquery es primero agrupar el max(level) y luego traerme solo ese, pero nada. Es frustrante.

Otro ejemplo mas rapido:

*

```
+-----------------+-------+-+------------+
|name             |level  | | victorias  |
+-----------------+-------+-+------------+
|a                |80 |     |   10       |
|a                |100|     |   100      |
|b                |100|     |   100      |
------------------------------------------
```

- 

**Debe traer el `a` de level `100` ¿Y como agrupo victorias? 

Debe traer el `b` de level `100` No hay problemas porque hay uno solo**

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y un ejemplo de los datos que esperas obtener como salida?, lo anterior por que al menos a mi se me hace complejo entender que buscas obtener

Comment: @BetaM okey, voy a poner un mini ejemplo que una vez leas todo el problema te va a alcarar, pero no tiene que ver. Muchas gracias

Comment: @josanangel No entiendo, quieres agrupar "name" y "victorias" por el maximo level? Si es asi, en victorias deberia mostrarse el nro de victorias de ese level?

Comment: @JuanRivera  en vic deberia salir la correspondiente al de max lvl

Comment: Que level consideras alto cuando los nombres son los mismos? Por lo que dices "*traer los pj con lvl mas altos con el mismo nombre*" 100? 200? 10000?

Comment: @JuanRivera Pues si los 3 tienen el mismo nombre debe de traer el 10000,

Comment: @JuanRivera  pueda que lo solucione hacer un distinct. Mañana voy a probarlo. Pues acabo de ver que para las agrupaciones si quieres evitar duplicados necesarios se puede usar un distinct. Mañana lo veo